# Open documents from Windows with Cygwin programs directly

Tags: windows, cygwin

Is it possible to open a document by using the Windows 10's *"open with"* feature with a program that comes with Cygwin, e.g. [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/)?

[image: Open-with]

This one with a Cygwin program.

**First attempt:** try to simply use the Cygwin program under Windows directly, i.e. the executable in `C:\cygwin64\bin` (in case of the standard install path).

Regardless of the *"open with"* problem, directly opening a Cygwin program often doesn't work well except for the most simple programs (no login shell is run first!).

So, starting the Cygwin X server, setting the Windows system environment variable `DISPLAY` (this gets [passed through](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html)) to `:0.0`, using *"open with"* on `C:\book.pdf` and choosing `C:\cygwin64\bin\zathura.exe` makes Zathura open the GUI window. But we get the error:

```
error: Unknown file type: 'cannot open `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/C:\book.pdf'    
(No such file or directory)'
```

❓

Obviously, something goes wrong with the path here.

**Second attempt:** work around the problem by using a Windows shortcut with the target:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c 'zathura "`cygpath "$0"`"'
```

At least that works for drag and drop in the Windows explorer. But again not with *"open with".*

As a minimal example create a Windows shortcut `emitpath.lnk` with the target:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c 'echo "`cygpath "$0"`" > out.path'
```

It works as expected again with dragging & dropping the document onto the shortcut: a file in the Cygwin home `out.path` is created and the "[cygwin-ified](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html)" path of the document is written into it. We got very close.

But, alas, with *"open with"* it does not work; nothing happens.

**So how to use *"open with"* with a Cygwin program on Windows 10?**

There must be an easier way than to create an executable wrapper.

Comment: First use `$()` instead of back-ticks. They are easier. Then you will have to show us what close looks like.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I don't understand the last sentence.

Comment: You said "We got very close.". What does this look like. I can not say head north, or head south, as I don't know in which direction you are close in. Tell us what happened. Describe what happened.

Comment: Put that it the question, so people don't have to read all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Make a batch file like:

```
@echo off
D:
chdir D:\cygwin64\bin
set A=%1
bash --login  -c "/usr/bin/echo $(cygpath  $A)"
pause
```

In the root directory of `Cygwin` should be present a `Cygwin.bat` to be used as
base.
Put the link to the batch file in the `SendTo` Folder

Now when I send a picture from my Pictures folder,
I have in a new CMD window:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Marco/Pictures/img250.jpg
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

The last is `Press any key` in German.
From here you can modify the batch to run any cygwin program you want.

If you plan to use the X server, it is probably better to have the Xwin server already running due to possible timing problem in the execution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with matzeri's solution is that it only works for the most sane filenames. A white space in the filename already breaks it.

Remember, if `C:\book 1.pdf` is the document to be opened, we want to end up with a string where on the bash side the escaping is correct - like this:

```
"/usr/bin/zathura \"$(cygpath 'C:\book 1.pdf')\""
```

But Windows passes the document path as an argument to a batch-script in two different ways:

- *"open with"*: *always* double-quoted.
- *"drag & drop"*: only *sometimes* double-quoted (when white spaces are present).

Because of the very abstruse escape rules of the batch language, it's probably better to use a lot of intermediate variables to build the string; otherwise you'll get insane.

We can use:

- `^` escapes the `"`. But only in unquoted strings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/5767184)!
- `set x=%x:"=%` is a substitution of `"` by nothing in the string in variable `x`.
- The single quote `'` is a normal character and does not need to be escaped.

So the following batch file does the job:

```
@echo off
C:
cd C:\cygwin64\bin
set pdfpath=%1
set pdfpath=%pdfpath:"=%
set cygpart=$(cygpath '%pdfpath%')
set fullcmd=/usr/bin/zathura \^"%cygpart%\^"
bash -l -c "%fullcmd%"
pause
```

There may be some strange filename which still breaks it. But at least it works for all somewhat normal filenames, including ones containing white spaces, parentheses, brackets.